# Bash script case menu from output of grep

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, case

Hello i need to make a simple bash script which makes a simple menu from a grep output. 
This is the grep part of the script that i have made so far:

```
x=1
ls /dev/ | grep USB | while read -r line ; do
    echo "$x DEVICE $line"
    x=$(( $x + 1 ))
done
```

Sample output:

```
1 DEVICE ttyUSB0
2 DEVICE ttyUSB1
3 DEVICE ttyUSB2
```

The user should then be able to choose one of these outputs from for example a case menu and then revoke some code. for example:

```
sudo kermit -C "set line /dev/$line",set carrier-watch off","connect"
```

where `$line` is the ttyUSB device.

i know how to make a static case menu. I just cant figure out how to make a dynamic one from the grep output.

Comment: shouldn't you be using `dialog`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```sh
x=1
for line in /dev/*USB*; do
    dev=$(basename "$line")
    devices[$x]=$dev
    echo "$x DEVICE $dev"
    x=$((x+1))
done
read -p "Which device? " devnum
line=$devices[$devnum]
```

You could also use the built-in `select` command:

```
lines=( $(ls /dev/ | grep USB) )
PS3="Pick a device:"
select devnum in $lines; do
    line=$REPLY
    break
done
```

Comment: Thank you @Barmar
The final script looks like this

#!/bin/bash

x=1

for line in /dev/*USB*; do

    dev=$(basename "$line")

    devices[$x]=$dev

    echo "$x DEVICE $dev"
    x=$((x+1))

done

read -p "Which device? " devnum

line=${devices[$devnum]}

echo "you chose $line"

sudo kermit -C "set line /dev/$line","set carrier-watch off","connect"